# How do I Programatically Determine if an Index Column is ASC or DESC

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing

The following query creates a list of all index names in the database a long with each column that is part of that index. Can someone tell me how to determine if the column is sorted ASC or DESC?

```
SELECT     ind.name as index_name     ,
           t.[name] as table_name     ,
           col.name as column_name     ,
           ic.index_column_id as index_column_id 
FROM [GDI-193-DEV].sys.indexes ind  
       INNER JOIN [GDI-193-DEV].sys.index_columns ic      
            ON  ind.object_id = ic.object_id and ind.index_id = ic.index_id  
       INNER JOIN [GDI-193-DEV].sys.columns col      
           ON ic.object_id = col.object_id and ic.column_id = col.column_id  
       INNER JOIN [GDI-193-DEV].sys.tables t      
           ON ind.object_id = t.object_id  
WHERE  ind.is_primary_key = 0 AND ind.is_disabled = 0 
ORDER BY      
       t.name, ind.name, ind.index_id, ic.index_column_id
```

Thanks!
Matt

Comment: Add `ASC` or `DESC` to the end of your `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Maybe you can check if the column first row value is > or < than the column last row value. But Mike is right, the best way to do this is to add the ORDER BY statement

Comment: For primary keys, `index_column_id` is *not* the order of the columns in the key, but in the table! Use `key_ordinal` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Table [`sys.index_columns`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175105%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) has a column `is_descending_key`

> 1 = Index key column has a descending sort direction.
>   0 = Index key column has an ascending sort direction.
>   Does not apply to columnstore indexes which return 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not specified any sorting order then by default it takes it as **ASCENDING**. Also you can add the **ORDER BY** statement to check that

From [Creating Ascending and Descending Indexes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933132%28v=sql.80%29.aspx):

> When defining indexes, you can specify whether the data for each
>   column is stored in ascending or descending order. **If neither
>   direction is specified, ascending is the default**, which maintains
>   compatibility with earlier versions of Microsoft® SQL Server™.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name,is_descending_key
FROM sys.indexes I , sys.index_columns IC
WHERE I.object_id=IC.object_id
```

This code gives us the name of index and asc/desc situation.